# react-navigation: useFocusEffect is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I have a react-native application and I would like to execute a function every time a particular screen's state become "focused". Based on the documentation ([link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/function-after-focusing-screen.html)), `useFocusEffect` is what I should use, here's my code:

```
import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native'

export default function ProfileScreen(props) {
  const {loading} = props.store
  const [deviceId, setDeviceId] = React.useState(null)
  const [questionIndex, setQuestionIndex] = React.useState(0)

  console.log(useFocusEffect)

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      console.log('here')
      //AsyncStorage.getItem('deviceId', (err, result) => {
      //  if (result !== null) {
      //    setDeviceId(result)
      //    props.dispatch({type: "STOP_LOADER"})
      //  }
      //})
    }, [])
  )
```

The problem is that when the app loads I get this error:

```
TypeError: (0, _native.useFocusEffect) is not a function.
```

The version I'm using is the this one: `"@react-navigation/native": "^3.6.2",`, how can I fix this?

EDIT: the problem was that the current version of react-navigation doesn't support hooks yet, waiting for the v5.0 release, I'm using this library as fallback: https://github.com/react-navigation/hooks

Comment: The link you provided is version:next, the latest version with tag next is: 5.0.0-alpha.18. 3.6.2 is the latest stable version which doesn't include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do 
`npm install --save @react-navigation/native@4.0.0-alpha.2`

3.6.2 is the latest stable version. You can find all versions of react-navigation here (under versions)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-navigation/native

Comment: this command ruined my whole project causing the error :
Unable to resolve "./throwIfWrongVersion" from "node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\index.js"

Comment: The latest version contains useFocusEffect now. Just change the version to the latest and delete+reinstall your node modules

Answer (score 0):

Hooks like useFocusEffect are available from version 4. If you cannot upgrade to version 4, check out the documentation for version 3: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/getting-started.html

Comment: I already have `react-navigation` version 4.0.5 but when I do `npm i @react-navigation/native` it installs only the version 3.6.2, how can I update it?

Answer (score 0):

npm WARN deprecated @react-navigation/native@4.0.0-alpha.2: Don't use

Read the output of: npm i --save @react-navigation/native to find the latest version

npm i --save @react-navigation/native@^5.0.5